# Insert values from two different tables into another different table with concatenate

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a button which uses two separate queries that pull data from two tables and insert into another table:

```
Dim lngID As Long
Dim lngIDCallout As Long
Dim strSQL1 As String

lngID = CalloutAttendance_MultiSelect.Value
lngIDCallout = Forms![Callouts].[CalloutID].Value

strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO Members_Callouts(MemberID) SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE MemberID=" & lngID    
strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO Members_Callouts(CalloutID) SELECT CalloutID FROM Callouts WHERE CalloutID=" & lngIDCallout

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL1
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL2
CalloutAttendance_MultiSelect.Requery
```

And whilst it almost does what I want it to do, it inserts the the two values as two separate new records, whereas I'd like it to insert it into ONE new record. I've had a go, but I either get syntax errors, or in the case below, I got a 3067 runtime error "Query input must contain at least one table or query"

```
strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO Members_Callouts(MemberID, CalloutID) SELECT
          (SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE MemberID=" & lngID & "),
          (SELECT CalloutID FROM Callouts WHERE CalloutID=" & lngIDCallout & ")"
```

Anyone know where I might be going wrong?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you're just inserting the key values so all you need to do is

```
strSQL1 = _
        "INSERT INTO Members_Callouts (MemberID, CalloutID) " & _
            "VALUES (" & lngID & ", " & lngIDCallout & ")"
```

In other words, you don't need to bother with something like...

```
"(SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE MemberID=" & lngID & ")"
```

...since the value it returns is just `lngId` (assuming that the value exists in the [Members] table).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO
  MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7)
SELECT
  f1.col1, f2.col2, f3.col3, f3.col4, f3.col5, f4.col6, f5.col7
FROM
  (SELECT Col1 FROM Func1())           AS f1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col2 FROM Func2())           AS f2
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col3,Col4,Col5 FROM Func3()) AS f3
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col6 FROM Func4())           AS f4
CROSS JOIN
```

(SELECT Col7 FROM Func5())           AS f5